# Asp.net and ImageMagick: someone can help me with an example?

Tags: asp.net, image-processing

maybe my question is generic. I would like to know how can i do a resize image when user upload it to my web site, and i'm a little confused.

I know exists ImageMagick ... but i don't know how to install and use it.

1.) What i've to copy in bin folder ? Only convert.exe ? Or maybe all DLL's found here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx

2.) After that, for a simple resize of 50% for example, which command i've to run ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say that you do not need to use ImageMagick only for one resize... **you can do image resize with few asp.net lines code** - why to use some dll with too many features that you never going to use ?

take a look on this example

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111640/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012203-1.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/04/02/resizing-images-without-loss-of-quality.aspx

or just google:**asp.net image resize**

Comment: Your consideration is correct. I thought using imagemagick was simpler than other solutions.